# Prevent local line spacing in command to be overwritten

Tags: tikz-styles, line-spacing

I want to change line spacing locally inside a custom command. However, the final `renewcommand` overwrites line spacing in the custom command. How can I locally set line spacing and prevent it to be overwritten?

I am aware of other methods of setting line spacing but since I am modifying a code which doesn't belong to me, I want to stick to `baselinestretch`.

**test.sty:**

```
\xdef\@singlespaced{1}

\newcommand\lalala{
    \let\baselinestretch\@singlespaced{
        sdfhjsdkfh sfjkhsdjfhs sdfkhskdjfhs dfksdhfjkshdf jkhsdkfjhsdkjf hskjdfhksjfh skjfh skjdfhksjf hskjdfhskjdfh skjfh skjfh skjdfh skjdhf skdf
    }
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
```

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{test}

\begin{document}
    \lalala
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\1`? When I run your example, I get an `undefined control sequence` error. Are you trying to set `\baselinestretch` to `1`?

Comment: @schtandard Sorry edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the text size after changing `\baselinestretch` for it to take effect. For the change to be local, you should put it *inside* the group, not before it. Since `\baselinestretch` always affects whole paragraph, you need to make the content of `\lalala` a separate paragraph from the surrounding text.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\lalala{%
    \par
    {\def\baselinestretch{1}\normalsize
        sdfhjsdkfh sfjkhsdjfhs sdfkhskdjfhs dfksdhfjkshdf jkhsdkfjhsdkjf hskjdfhksjfh skjfh skjdfhksjf hskjdfhskjdfh skjfh skjfh skjdfh skjdhf skdf%
        \par
    }%
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\lalala
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Do we need the first `\par`? I still get single line spacing without it. Also, what do you mean with "make the content of `\lalala` one"?

Comment: What I meant was that we need to make the content of `\lalala` a separate paragraph from the surrounding text. I changed the wording accordingly. This is why the first `\par` is necessary; otherwise the whole paragraph (including `\lipsum[1]`) is set with a `\baselinestretch` of `1`.

Comment: By the way, if you are unhappy with the uneven spacing around the tighter paragraph, you can put it inside a `\parbox` or `minipage`.

Comment: Thanks. I learned I lot from a single answer.